# Generics class method taking function parameter of the generic type doesn't work with Void

Tags: generics, haxe

I've run into a Haxe issue that seems really odd to me.. Is it a bug ?

When creating a generic class with a method taking a function of the generic type as a parameter i get the weird error

Void -> Void should be (Void) -> Void

When the generic type is Void

If the generic type is Int it works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas to fix or work around this ?

[Playground link](http://try.haxe.org/#83E4D)

```
class Test {
    static var test2:Test2<Void> = new Test2<Void>();
    static public function main() {
        test2.test(passedFunc);
    }

    static function passedFunc():Void {
        trace("passedFunc");
    }
}

class Test2<T> {
    public function new():Void {}

    public function test(func: T->Void) {
        trace("Test2.testFunc(T)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trick the type inference to *almost* ignore the missing argument like so:

```
class Test {
    static var test2 = new Test2();
    static public function main() {
        test2.test(passedFunc);
    }
    static function passedFunc(?unused):Void {
        trace("passedFunc");
    }
}    
class Test2<T> {
    public function new():Void {}
    public function test(func: T->Void) {
        trace("Test2.testFunc(T)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's a bug, it could just be related to the way the Type system works in Haxe.  In any case, one workaround you could use is to simply have a function where the parameter is explicity typed `Void->Void` and use your parameterized type `T` in other functions of the class when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
static public function main() {
    test2.test(cast passedFunc);
}
```

[Playground link](http://try.haxe.org/#D5CcC).